# How to use CVS inside Android project to maintain the version history?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have Googled a lot for SVN, GIT and CVS. Only thing that I understand that It is used for maintains of the software project that we have develop. They are used for maintains of Current and Historical versions.

- For Git I have referred to [this user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide)
- For SVN I have refer to [this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/)

I have implemented the CVS repository on my system by taking the help of [this article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#eclipsesourcecode)

Now I can see the task and CVS repository inside Eclipse, but I don't know how to use my project inside the CVS. How it maintains version?

None of the link explain how to maintain any project or any small example. Can any one please help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want to understand the basics of version control system. I'd recommed you read Joel Spolsky's [HgInit](http://hginit.com/) which teaches the basics of version control.

General steps on working with *any* version control system:

- Create a repository which holds the source code.
- Set ignore files which will ignore changes done to particular files, such as binaru files(images etc)
- Create a branch
- Start working on a file. When you've reached a logical end point(say, added a method, created a new class) commit the changes.
- Repeat
- Maintain separate branches for new features & for bug defects
- Regularly merge them so that your bug defects are included in the new features branch
- Create a release branch when your project is ready to be released.
- So on.

I'm sure others will point you to use a more Modern VCS like Mercurial/Git, if you're still interested in CVS look at these 2:

- [Getting Started with CVS](http://www.linux.ie/articles/tutorials/cvs.php)
- [CVS Tutorial](http://vasc.ri.cmu.edu/old_help/Archiving/Cvs/cvs_tutorial.texinfo_toc.html)

Comment: Thanks Sathya. I will try with the above link.